# Why are time-based deliveries sometimes not awarded an S rating even though delivery time was within the limit?

Tags: death-stranding

I've had several time-based deliveries that did not get an S rating, even though the delivery time was well under the specified limit.  In these cases, I am playing on Hard difficulty and going for Premium Delivery.

In the past, I chalked it up to making partial deliveries for large cargo orders, thinking that to get the Premium award I needed to deliver it all at once. However, I just completed an order for the First Prepper, delivered all of the cargo in one trip and made it in 8:25 for a 35-minute limit.  See attached photo.

There must be some qualification I missed, I just don't know what it was.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For time based deliveries, your rank depends on how fast you take to complete the delivery. For a 30 minute time limit, I believe it's sub-5 minute for S rank. It looks like you don't have the time in that yellow highlighting, so you definitely took too long.

Answer (score 7):

You need to complete order in less than 20% (or 1/5) of order time limit. So to get S rating for 35 minute limit order you need to complete it in less than 7 minutes.

Cargo damage also affects results:

> Scenarios for 25 minutes premium delivery (hard):
>
> - Completed with 5:20 (0% damage) - RATED A
> - Completed with 4:30 (9% damage) - RATED A
> - Completed with 4:30 (6% damage) - RATED S

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/DeathStranding/comments/dw47if/question_about_the_premium_deliveries_and_the/)